# AND operator not working

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

The AND operator (+) is not working. It seems to have no effect. Is there something special I have to do to enable this?

I´m using the is.microsoft analyzer that came with the 2015-02-28-Preview version.

Comment: You need to provide code showing what you did, the result you got and the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you URL encoded the search string?  If you have not encoded it, it will be interpreted as a space which would explain why it is being ignored.